# Jboss for beginners

Tags: web-applications, jboss, application-server

I know that questions of that kind are usually not desirable, but I still think I can rely on your help. I would like to have an indication of a decent tutorial/documentation of Jboss which cites its basic and widespread applications along with some simple examples. I have sought meticulously till now, however I could not find anything that satisfies me substantially.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

start here  - [hello world](http://www.centerkey.com/jboss/)
Than jump here  - [jboss ejb3 tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

Besides the [JBoss documentation](http://www.jboss.org), you can find a large set of [JBoss tutorials here](http://www.mastertheboss.com). 
Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of official examples for JBoss 7 at: http://www.jboss.org/jdf/examples/get-started/
You can import them into your IDE and easily deploy to JBoss.